# Iceweasel crashes after loading in linux on android

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, arm, iceweasel

I installed Kali Linux via Linux Deploy on my rooted G2x running CM 7 and everything is fine, however I installed Iceweasel and now it begins loading a webpage then crashes, the term output is

```
$ iceweasel
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".

(iceweasel:5847): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 38 (Function not implemented)
Segmentation fault
$
```

any ideas?

Comment: Looks like /dev/shm is missing. Is SYSVIPC support turned on in your Linux kernel?

Comment: shm is listed in /dev, and i'm not sure about how to check to see if my kernel supports SYSVIPC.

Comment: `zgrep CONFIG_SYSVIPC /proc/config.gz` or, if there is no config.gz,
`grep CONFIG_SYSVIPC /boot/config*`